# Previous year MTD and YTD query in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

am using MS SQL 2014.

i have a situation where i need to display the data in MTD,YTD,Previous year MTD and Previous YTD.

I have wrote the query for MTD and YTD for current year (as per the date input)

ex: 
1) MTD (current year) :

DBP.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@RefDate),0) AND @RefDate

2) YTD (current year) :

DBP.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@RefDate),0) AND @RefDate

i have searched in the forums on previous year MTD and YTD but couldnt find.

it would be very helpfull if anyone could help in writing the previous year MTD and YTD.

Thanks.

Comment: show inputs and expected results.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: What have you done so far?  How can we help if you don't show anything?

Comment: i have a situation  where i need to display the MTD, YTD , previous year MTD and previous YTD. 

I wrote query for MTD and YTD (current year) as per the given input date.
ex: MTD: DBP1.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@RefDate),0) AND @RefDate

Comment: i have modified my question please refer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to write myself for the Last year MTD and YTD as below.

**LastYear MTD:**

```
DAY(DBP1.Date) <= DAY(@RefDate)
AND
MONTH(DBP1.Date) = MONTH(@RefDate)
AND
YEAR(DBP1.Date) = YEAR(@RefDate)-1
```

**LastYear YTD:**

```
YEAR(DBP1.Date) = YEAR(@RefDate)-1
AND
((MONTH(DBP1.Date) < MONTH(@RefDate))
OR ((MONTH(DBP1.Date) = MONTH(@RefDate)) AND (DAY(DBP1.Date) <=        DAY(@RefDate))))
```

Thanks